# Массив данных json и распечатка на экран с помощью javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, php7

PHP:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $result_search_cat[] = array('label' => $row['title']);
}
exit( json_encode($result_search_cat) );
```

Принимаю json данные и обрабатываю их:

```
success: function(res){
   var result = JSON.parse(res);
   ...//Код
}
```

В **Firebug** приходят данные отлично:

```
[{"label":"Flat \u0441able iPod nano 6G with on\/off button and volume"},{"label":"Flat Cable on\/off
 iPod touch 4G"},{"label":"On\/off outside home iPod Touch 4G (black)"},{"label":"On\/off outside home
 iPod Touch 4G (white)"},{"label":"Hands-free connector iPod Touch 4G"}]
```

Но я не могу их вывести на экран. Такой код не помогает:

```
for (var i in result.label){
    console.log("Ключ = " + i + "; Значение = " + result.label[i]);
}
```

Что я делаю не так подскажите, пожалуйста,

Comment: result.label это строка
а вам нужно бежать по объектам

Comment: @ Vitalii Подскажите, как это сделать.

Comment: result.forEach(function(item){console.log(item)});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` - означает что в jsone массив обьектов, то-есть после `JSON.parse` мы получим обычный массив :

```js
var result = JSON.parse('[{"label":"Flat \u0441able iPod nano 6G with on\/off button and volume"},{"label":"Flat Cable on\/off iPod touch 4G"},{"label":"On\/off outside home iPod Touch 4G (black)"},{"label":"On\/off outside home iPod Touch 4G (white)"},{"label":"Hands-free connector iPod Touch 4G"}]');

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  console.log(result[i]['label']);
}
```

Просто бежим по массиву, и в каждой итерации что-то делаем с попавшимся обьектом

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое:) То что нужно:)

Answer (score 0):

вывод в дом спец развернул для понимания

```js
let result = JSON.parse('[{"label":"Flat \u0441able iPod nano 6G with on\/off button and volume"},{"label":"Flat Cable on\/off iPod touch 4G"},{"label":"On\/off outside home iPod Touch 4G (black)"},{"label":"On\/off outside home iPod Touch 4G (white)"},{"label":"Hands-free connector iPod Touch 4G"}]');

// просто вывод в консоль
result.forEach( item => console.log(item.label));

// простой вывод в дом 
let ul = document.createElement('ul');
result.forEach( item => {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = item.label;
  ul.appendChild(li)
});
document.body.appendChild(ul);
```